# Best way to select key-value pairs randomly

Tags: java, key

I'm designing a program that selects random key-pairs as long as they are below a certain threshold.

So lets say I have these as my key-pairs:

```
Padded=1
Leather=2
Studded Leather=3
Hide=4
Scale Mail=5
```

Ideally I would only be able to select combinations of one or more key-pairs that add up to be below a certain number, then print the text of the chosen ones to the screen.

What would be the best way to store the key-pairs that is easily editable and somewhat efficient, as well as can be randomly selected from. I will probably end up with 200+ key-pairs.

Comment: You normally store key-value pairs in a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to efficiently access the values by key as well as be able to get them randomly, you could use a combination of `Map` and `List`. If you want to access a random pair, you should also declare some custom class representing the pair.

The `Map` will store the key-value pairs, and the `List` will just store the keys - that will enable you to use a random number to get a random pair.

In your case it could look like this:

```
class Pair {

    private final String key;
    private int value;

    public Pair(String key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key + ": " + value;
    }
}

class Pairs {

    private static final Random RND = new Random();
    private List<String> list =  new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, Pair> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void addPair(String key, int value) {
        list.add(key);
        map.put(key, new Pair(key, value));
    }

    public Pair getPair(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public Pair getRandomPair() {
        return map.get(list.get(RND.nextInt(list.size())));
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
Pairs pairs = new Pairs();
pairs.addPair("Padded", 1);
pairs.addPair("Leather", 2);
pairs.addPair("Hide", 4);
pairs.getPair("Hide").setValue(3);
System.out.println(pairs.getPair("Hide").getValue());
System.out.println(pairs.getRandomPair());
```